# Multiplying vectors from the same list and printing the highest 2 outputs

Tags: python, list

I have a function that multiplies 2 vectors

```
mltply(vec1, vec2)
```

I also have a list with n number of vectors.

```
vectors_list = [array([1,2,4],dtype=float32), array([2,2,1],dtype=float32), array([3,5,1], dtype=float32)]
```

I would like to multiply each vector in the list of arrays by each other vector in the list, and then print 3 highest results.

I tried the following , but it does not work.

```
for vec in vectors_list:
        print(mltply(vec,vec1) for vec, vec1 in zip(vectors_list,vectors_list[1:]))
```

Comment: What is the return type for your multiplication function? Float? np.array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to multiply each vector in the list of arrays by each other vector in the list:

```
import itertools

result = [mltply(v1, v2) for v1, v2 in itertools.combinations(vectors_list, 2)]
```

to print the 3 highest results you can use the built-in function `sorted`, or you can sort inline the list using `list.sort` then slice the top 3 elements:

```
print(sorted(result)[-3:])
```

or:

```
result.sort()
print(result[-3:])
```